How can i replicate a Dlookup from a MS Access query in a Power BI Query?
I have a series of tables that I want to put into Power BI to run analytics on. There are 2 tables.
Table 1 - Every time a patient is moved to a ward, a new entry is made in this table with the date/time, their admissionID and the ward they are on:



admissionID
Ward
Date-Time




12345
1
01-01-2000


12345
2
02-02-2000


19999
8
02-02-2000



Then I have Table 2, that records when a user records an activity against an admissionID:



admitID
User
Field-Changed
Change-Date-Time




12345
BobSmith
Name Field
05-01-2000


12345
BobSmith
Country Field
05-01-2000


19999
DaveMatthews
Address Field
06-02-2000



In these examples above, I want to know that for the changes that Bob Smith made, that based on the time of the change, that the patient was on ward 1 at that time, not ward 2.
In MS Access, I used this code to get the ward at that time:
Ward: DLast("[Ward]","Table1","[admissionID]=" & [admitID] & " AND [Date-Time]<#" & Format([Change-Date-Time],"mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM") & "#")

How can I replicate the output of this Access query in Power BI?
Some thoughts I had but I don't think are correct:

Do an append query in Power BI, and then create a new column which compares Date-Time to Change-Date-Time. That column can show True or False if the Date-Time is less than Change-Date-Time, but the problem is there could be multiple entries before that, hence the use of the DLast in MS Access


I would link the tables in power bi and then something like this
LastWardMeasure = 
VAR CurrentAdmissionID = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[admitID])
VAR CurrentChangeDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Change-Date-Time])
RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    LASTNONBLANK(Table1[Ward], Table1[Date-Time]),
    FILTER(
        Table1, 
        Table1[admissionID] = CurrentAdmissionID && 
        Table1[Date-Time] < CurrentChangeDate
    )
)

LASTNONBLANK retrieves the most recent Ward value for the given admitID where the Date-Time is less than Change-Date-Time.

Thanks for the reply. I think the code above was meant to say Table2 for the 2 variables
But it still gives me an error for the second argument in the LASTNONBLANK:
A single value for column 'Date-Time' in table 'Table1' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.
